# How to search for files that don't have the input string in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, search

I'm wonder to search files that don't have the input. For example I have the files `AAB` , `ABC` , `BC`, `DE`  and ...

I want to search for files that don't have `A` in their names. Like this output :  `BC` , `DE` ...

Is there any way to do it ?
I know Windows search use regular expressions to search, Then can it done by regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(*a*), -(*A*)
```

Should work according to you saying regular expressions are used in search.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. tnx

Comment: You can widen your search criterias by researching in RE.